# Estimation precision of lower- vs. higher-order moments

Tags: estimation, moments, finance

I have a vague feeling that for a fixed sample size, lower-order moments of a distribution would typically be estimated more precisely than higher-order moments. E.g. mean would be estimated more precisely than the second moment.

1. How do I phrase this formally?*
2. Is this correct (perhaps under certain conditions)? What are the conditions for this to hold?

The question is motivated by the following thread at Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange: ["Why is asset volatility easier to estimate than the asset mean if it contains the mean?"](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57514)

*There are different measures of precision and I wonder which one(s) may make most sense; perhaps there is a standard way of thinking about this problem that I am not aware of.

Comment: asking for measures of precision while saying that there are different ones without furnishing the post with some examples might distract the average responder from the real question at hand: moment estimation

Comment: Also it's irrelevant if you think that lower order moments are easier to estimate. The real question might actually be whether **even vs odd moments** of financial data are easier to estimate. Also, some people don't automatically recognize that mean and variance are **"lower-order moments"**, so it might have to be spelled out for them in order to avoid drawing blanks

Comment: @develarist, thanks, I will see if I can incorporate your suggestions in the post. The question is about lower- vs. higher-order moments, not even vs. odd; that would be a separate question. The real-world interpretation of the random variables is immaterial for the question. Variance is a *central* moment, so its estimation precision is a bit tangential to the question.

Comment: The title of the link seems to suggest that a higher moment (2nd - variance) is estimated more precisely ("easier") than a lower (mean - 1st moment), unlike what you (and I) intuitively feel?!

Comment: @ChristophHanck, yes, indeed. This is why I found it interesting and started digging deeper.

Comment: If you look into rates of convergence, most estimators for higher moments converge slower than estimates for lower order moments. However, there is one area where this is not true: financial return forecasting. Forecasting returns is difficult simply because if it were easy, many people would do it and that would quickly eat up the forecasted return leaving no more for others. This is one of the few cases where a moment is the result of an equilibrium which perturbs the moment. So, apart from that problem domain, look into asymptotics. Ferguson or Severini might be useful reference texts.

Comment: @kurtosis, thanks for the comment. Could you cite Feguson and Severini fully? I am not familiar with the names. Also, I am looking for a statistical argument, not a financial one. Financial returns can certainly be modeled statistically, and I want an answer based on a statistical model. Let me point out that finance and statistics cannot clash on this question because they operate in tangential worlds. Saying that financial returns disobey statistical laws (I am not saying you do that, but there seems to be a hint) because of some financial reasons is an apples-and-oranges kind of argument.

Comment: @kurtosis, also, the counterexample provided in the answer by Christoph Hanck is pretty telling. It indicates that asymptotic convergence rates do not suggest mean should be estimated more precisely than variance for all sizes (true parameter values) of means and variances.

Comment: Severini _Elements of Distribution Theory_ and Ferguson _A Course in Large Sample Theory_. That counterexample presumes normality; lots of distributions are not normal: wait or failure times, log-likelihoods, posterior probabilities, and (eek) ratios of random variables are all not normal. So that counterexample is by no means universal or prevalent even. The reason financial returns break the typical hierarchy of estimation ease IS a statistical argument: the data generation process results from an equilibrium affected by the mean. I suppose you could think of that like a curved distribution.

Comment: @kurtosis, thank you! Regarding normality, I agree. Regarding the statistical argument, what do you mean by *the data generation process results from an equilibrium affected by the mean*? Could you formulate this mathematically? Could you write down the simplest possible statistical model that would illustrate your point?

Comment: I can't exactly write down a statistical model; it ends up being a dynamic model with statistical drivers but there's an equilibrium that gets solved for in light of the randomness. That's why it's so danged hard to beat the market: if it were not, everyone would be doing it. I would say that trying to write down what that system should look like is one of the biggest areas of research in finance and economics. We have ideas: we think taking risk should yield some benefit; otherwise people would not take it and the price would rise until the risk were worth taking (for some people).

Comment: We also think diversification should help since the uncorrelated parts of random returns tend to cancel each other out (i.e. adding more mean-zero random variables gets a tighter cluster around 0). However, beyond that it gets tough. Some risks do not cancel out as you broaden your holdings: adding more stocks doesn't get you toward being unexposed to the overall economy. And all of that affects prices people pay for investments -- which affects their return (and especially the average return). Hopefully that helps explain why the mean is so challenging in finance.

Comment: @kurtosis, thank you, I appreciate your help. While the financial story makes sense to me, I do not see its statistical implications for the original question. As I have already tried to hint at somewhere in the thread cited in the OP, point prediction is not the same as estimation of the underlying first moment. To beat the market, you need a good point prediction. You argue point prediction is hard – OK. However, it is only partly relevant to the problem of estimating the mean and it does not imply that mean is particularly hard to estimate (the implication would only go the other way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I believe might be a counterexample if the intuition were a general claim, or at least a result that seems to indicate that the answer to 2. might be "not really". The measure of the precision of an estimator of a certain moment that I use here is the variance.

It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72975/variance-of-sample-variance) that the variance of the sample variance, when sampling from a normal population, is $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$, and that that of the mean is $\sigma^2/n$.

So, the former is larger if
$$\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}>\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$ or $$\sigma^2>\frac{n-1}{2n},$$
which evidently need not be the case.

```
n <- 10
sigma.sq <- 4/10 # 9/20 or 4.5/10 would be cutoff here

sim.mean.s2 <- function(n){
  x <- rnorm(n, sd=sqrt(sigma.sq))
  xbar <- mean(x)
  s2 <- var(x)
  return(list(xbar, s2))
}

sims <- matrix(unlist(replicate(1e6, sim.mean.s2(n))), nrow=2)

var(sims[1,]) # may also try moments::moment(sims[1,],2, central=T) to simulate population variance, but does not matter at many replications
sigma.sq/n

var(sims[2,])
2*sigma.sq^2/(n-1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is insightful. So essentially there is no good reason to have the general feeling I was having? :)

Comment: Apparently not - nor to have the one I had, too...:) It might be the case that in the real world $\sigma^2>1$ is common, so that the above inequality often holds so that the intuition does have some empirical support (in any case, the example is somewhat restrictive in that it deals with the normal case and the first two moments only).

Comment: Definitely helpful nonetheless! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. What if you redo the analysis for standard deviation? Mean and variance are not in the same units so the comparison might be problematic.

Comment: That is a good point! Resorting to asymptotic approximations via the delta method, the standard deviation has asymptotic variance $\sigma^2/2$ (i.e., $\sqrt{n}(S-\sigma)\to_d N(0,\sigma^2/2)$, see https://hannig.cloudapps.unc.edu/STOR655/handouts/Handout-asymptotics.pdf) while the mean has asymptotic variance $\sigma^2$, which evidently implies a smaller variance of the standard deviation. Should we still call it a "higher" moment if it has the same units as the mean, though?

Comment: Stocks are more Cauchy than normal.  The real world is limited in sample size, and so that makes real error higher than analytics assuming infinite samples might suggest.  Quantitative finance might suggest a non-normal distribution either Cauchy or even uniform.